# Angular2 ngstyle is not working when update variable

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to use ngstyle to show or hide my nav bar, which is child component for controller component.

Controller Html

```
<section>
    <app-nav class="nav" [ngStyle]="{'visibility':isNavShow?'visible':'hidden'}"></app-nav>
    <app-main class="main"></app-main>
</section>
```

Controller Comp

```
isNavShow:boolean = false;
subRouterParam:Subscription = new Subscription();

constructor(private accountService: AccountService,private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('account id:'+this.accountService.userData.id);
    this.subRouterParam = this.route.params.subscribe(
        (data)=> {
            this.isNavShow = data['isNavShow']==undefined?false:data['isNavShow'];
        }
    );
}

ngDoCheck(){
    console.log(this.isNavShow);
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subRouterParam.unsubscribe();
}
```

Controller Module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ConsoleComponent,
        NavComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        MainModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    providers:[TagService]
})
export class ConsoleModule{}
```

I have logged `isNavShow` value, I am pretty sure `isNavShow` toggle value but the ngstyle is not updated!
The strange thing is that I set `hidden` in the begin, and the first time toggle from `hidden` to `visible` works. However, ngStyle did not change anymore even the `isNavShow` changed.

[update!] I change the nav bar to this format, the `isNavShow` indeed change correctly. But the ngStyle is not working..

```
<div class="nav" [ngStyle]="{'visibility':isNavShow?'visible':'hidden'}">{{isNavShow}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Params from router can only be strings because they come from the URL.

Try this:

```
this.isNavShow = data['isNavShow'] && data['isNavShow'].toLowerCase() === 'true';
```